# How do I add posting date on json instagram api

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, date, instagram-api

I am having trouble figuring out the proper structure for adding the date in my json instagram feed.

Here is an example of the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/galnova/p74jy3sk/

Here is the code with the commented out date portion that I cannot get to work.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

 var accessToken = '271323200.1677ed0.67c49d5002704bc09c3c77320ec138a2'; // use your own token
 var date = new Date(parseInt(data.data[i].created_time) * 1000);

        m = date.getMonth();
        d = date.getDate();
        y = date.getFullYear();

        var month_names = new Array ( );
        month_names[month_names.length] = "Jan";
        month_names[month_names.length] = "Feb";
        month_names[month_names.length] = "Mar";
        month_names[month_names.length] = "Apr";
        month_names[month_names.length] = "May";
        month_names[month_names.length] = "Jun";
        month_names[month_names.length] = "Jul";
        month_names[month_names.length] = "Aug";
        month_names[month_names.length] = "Sep";
        month_names[month_names.length] = "Oct";
        month_names[month_names.length] = "Nov";
        month_names[month_names.length] = "Dec";

  $.getJSON('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token='+accessToken+'&callback=?',function (insta) {
    $.each(insta.data,function (photos,src) {
      if ( photos === 200 ) { return false; }
         // template
      $(
        '<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 grip_wrap">' +
          '<div class="grip_hang_topp"></div>' +
          '<div class="col-xs-12 grip">' +
            '<a class="fancybox zero" rel="gallery1" href="' + this.images.standard_resolution.url + '">' +
              '<img src="' + this.images.standard_resolution.url + '" />' +
            '</a>' +
            '<div class="description">' + this.user.username + '</div>' +
        '<span class="right col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-12 heart-wrap floated">' + '<i class="fa fa-heart">'+ '</i>' + this.likes.count +' likes'+'</span>' +
        '<span class="left col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-12 comment-wrap floated">' + '<i class="second fa fa-comment">'+ '</i>' + this.comments.count +' comments'+'</span>' +
(date.getMonth()+1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear() +
          '</div>' +
          '<div class="grip_hang_bott"></div>' +
        '</div>'
      ).appendTo('#instafeed');
    }); 
  });
});
</script>
```

My javascript knowledge is limited. I have looked online for solutions and have found none with this json format. Any help is welcome.

Comment: instead of `'(date.getMonth()+1)' + 'date.getDate()' + 'date.getFullYear()' +` try `(date.getMonth()+1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear() +`

Comment: I just tried this the console error Im getting is date not defined

Comment: I tried to fix it but now I am getting a data error

Comment: You uncommented where it is declared?

Comment: It's no longer loading on my page here galnova.com

Comment: what is `data.data[i].created_time`

Comment: I am not sure..I tried to use this code https://gist.github.com/halfempty/d5dd9b636b69ffa2e5c5 and wasn't quite sure how it all worked.

Comment: well, where are you trying to get a date from - you can't just type a random string of keys and expect the object to exist :p

Comment: I wanted to pull the date from my instagram feed. I thought dates were already baked into jquery.

Comment: well, you need to figure out what you are using for the date, without any details of the data you are receiving, I can't help any further

Comment: this.likes.count pulls in likes this.comment.count pulls in the comments. I thought there was a this.date or something to let me dynamically pull it from Instagram.

Comment: well, inspect the data you receive ... `insta.data[0].created_time` looks a likely candidate - within your $.each loop, it'll be `this.created_time` ... you need to move the var date to the first line of the $.each ... `var date = new Date(parseInt(this.created_time) * 1000);`

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/p74jy3sk/1/

Comment: Oh interesting it gives me data back for that 1497658481 ... a random sequence of numbers though

Comment: YOU ARE AMAZING!!! Thank you!!!

Comment: it's not random ... `new Date(1497658481 * 1000)` = 17 June 2017 00:14:41 GMT

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to parsed date.

parsed value first:

`var parsedDate = new Date(1000*this.created_time);`

Then format using moment.js

`moment(parsedDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY')`

```js
$(function(){

  
 
 // tabbed menus
 
 //$('.menu .item').tab();
 
 // first script to pull posts
 
  var accessToken = '271323200.1677ed0.67c49d5002704bc09c3c77320ec138a2'; // use your own token
  
  $.getJSON('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token='+accessToken+'&callback=?',function (insta) {
  
    $.each(insta.data,function (photos,src) {
    var parsedDate = new Date(1000*this.created_time);
      if ( photos === 100 ) { return false; }
   // template
      $(
        '<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 grip_wrap">' +
          '<div class="grip_hang_topp"></div>' +
          '<div class="col-xs-12 grip">' +
            '<a class="fancybox zero" rel="gallery1" href="' + this.images.standard_resolution.url + '">' +
              '<img src="' + this.images.thumbnail.url + '" />' +
            '</a>' +
            '<div class="description">' + this.user.username + '</div>' +
     '<span class="right floated">' + '<i class="fa fa-heart">'+ '</i>' + this.likes.count +' 0 likes'+'</span>' +
     '<span class="left floated">' + '<i class="second fa fa-comment">'+ '</i>' + this.comments.count +' comments'+'</span> '+ moment(parsedDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY') + 
          '</div>' +
          '<div class="grip_hang_bott"></div>' +
        '</div>'
      ).appendTo('#instafeed');
    }); 
  });
 
// script to for search
//var accessToken = ''; // use your own token 
 /*
$('.ui.search')
  .search({
    type          : 'category',
    minCharacters : 200,
    apiSettings   : {
      onResponse: function(githubResponse) {
        var
          response = {
            results : {}
          }
        ;
        // translate GitHb API response to work with search
        $.each(githubResponse.items, function(index, item) {
          var
            language   = item.language || 'Unknown',
            maxResults = 200
          ;
          if(index >= maxResults) {
            return false;
          }
          // create new language category
          if(response.results[language] === undefined) {
            response.results[language] = {
              name    : language,
              results : []
            };
          }
          // add result to category
          response.results[language].results.push({
            title       : item.name,
            description : item.description,
            url         : item.html_url
          });
        });
        return response;
      },
      url: '//api.github.com/search/repositories?q={query}'
    }
  })
;
*/
});
```

```css
.ui.card .meta, .ui.cards > .card .meta { display: none; }

.ui.card > .content > .header+.description, .ui.card > .content>.meta + .description, .ui.cards > .card > .content > .header + .description, .ui.cards > .card > .content > .meta + .description { margin-top: 0; }

.ui.card > .extra, .ui.cards > .card > .extra { font-size: 10px; }

i { margin-right: 3px; }
.second { margin-left: 10px; }
.floated { font-size: 11px; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) { 
  .ui.card > .content > .header:not(.ui), .ui.cards>.card>.content>.header:not(.ui) {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 1em;
  }
  
  .ui.card > .content, .ui.cards > .card > .content { padding: .5em; }
}

/*-- --*/
.col-lg-1,
.col-lg-10,
.col-lg-11,
.col-lg-12,
.col-lg-2,
.col-lg-3,
.col-lg-4,
.col-lg-5,
.col-lg-6,
.col-lg-7,
.col-lg-8,
.col-lg-9,
.col-md-1,
.col-md-10,
.col-md-11,
.col-md-12,
.col-md-2,
.col-md-3,
.col-md-4,
.col-md-5,
.col-md-6,
.col-md-7,
.col-md-8,
.col-md-9,
.col-sm-1,
.col-sm-10,
.col-sm-11,
.col-sm-12,
.col-sm-2,
.col-sm-3,
.col-sm-4,
.col-sm-5,
.col-sm-6,
.col-sm-7,
.col-sm-8,
.col-sm-9,
.col-xs-1,
.col-xs-10,
.col-xs-11,
.col-xs-12,
.col-xs-2,
.col-xs-3,
.col-xs-4,
.col-xs-5,
.col-xs-6,
.col-xs-7,
.col-xs-8,
.col-xs-9 {
  padding: 8px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 28px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 8px;
}

h2 {
  /* border-top: dotted 2px blue; */
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.tupper {
  /* border-bottom: solid 2px blue; */
  padding: 0;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  margin: 0;
}

.main_wrap {
  padding-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: solid 2px blue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.grip_wrap:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 5px;
  background: blue;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
}

.grip_wrap:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 5px;
  background: blue;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
}


/* .grip_wrap:first-child:before { display: none; }
.grip_wrap:last-child:after { display: none; } */


/* .grip_wrap:nth-child(4n+4):after { display: none; } */


/* .grip_wrap:nth-child(5):before,
.grip_wrap:nth-child(9):before,
.grip_wrap:nth-child(13):before
{ display: none; } */


/* .grip_wrap:before > .grip:hover, .grip_wrap:after > .grip:hover { } */

.grip {
  /* opacity: .5; */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  min-width: 150px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 2px blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 18px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 18px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 18px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.grip:hover {
  border: solid 2px green;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.grip img {
  /* opacity: 0; */
  display: block;
  width: 124px;
  height: 124px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.grip a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 124px;
  height: 124px;
  margin: auto;
}

.grip .icent {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 124px;
  height: 124px;
  left: 50%;
}

.grip div {
  padding: 5px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 28px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  background: #cccccc;
}

.grip_hang_topp {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 50px;
  width: 5px;
  background: blue;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
}

.grip_hang_bott {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 50px;
  width: 5px;
  background: blue;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
}

.panel-body {
  padding: 0;
}

.panel {
  border-top: solid 2px blue;
  border-bottom: solid 2px blue;
}

.panel-default >.panel-heading {
  background: #ead554;
  border: none;
}

.panel-heading a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.0.47/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- <div class="ui bottom attached tab active" data-tab="first">-->
  <div class="ui container">
    <d**strong text**iv id="instafeed" class="ui three column doubling centered grid container"></div>
  </div>
<!--</div> -->
```